# the same event rowDblselecti n nested dataTables

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, datatable, nested

I have problem with nested datatables and event rowDblselect. If I use the same type of event in nested tables and then I do doubleclick on row in nested dataTable, or in parent dataTable, it caused exception com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0.

This code demonstrates problem or bug.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable1" value="list1">
<p:ajax event="rowDblselect"
             listener="listener1"/>

<p:column>
    test1
    <p:rowToggler /> 
</p:column>

<p:rowExpansion>

   <p:dataTable id="dataTable2" value="list2">
       <p:ajax event="rowDblselect"
                    listener="listener2"/>

       <p:column>
           test2
       </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>

</p:rowExpansion>
```

Please, can anybody help with this problem?
Very thanks.
JSF 2.2.3 Mojarra, Primefaces 4.0, Extensions 1.0
Tomcat 7.0.41

Stack trace:
This happened after doubleclick in parent table.

```
XI 19, 2013 12:29:00 ODP. com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
INFO: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:2458)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:2327)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.put(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:415)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.put(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:331)
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.setValue(MapELResolver.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:281)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:218)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:253)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.setValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:172)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processUpdates(DataTable.java:561)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.process(UIData.java:328)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:309)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:267)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processUpdates(UIData.java:257)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processUpdates(DataTable.java:556)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:554)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:675)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:263)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

XI 19, 2013 12:29:00 ODP. com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase execute
WARNING: java.lang.NullPointerException
XI 19, 2013 12:29:00 ODP. com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.convertArgs(AstValue.java:320)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:274)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.invoke(ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:477)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:53)
    at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:804)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1086)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

XI 19, 2013 12:29:00 ODP. com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.convertArgs(AstValue.java:320)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:274)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.invoke(ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:477)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:53)
    at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:804)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1086)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

XI 19, 2013 12:29:00 ODP. com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
INFO: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:2458)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:2327)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.put(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:415)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.put(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:331)
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.setValue(MapELResolver.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:281)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:218)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:253)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.setValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:172)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processUpdates(DataTable.java:561)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.process(UIData.java:328)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:309)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:267)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processUpdates(UIData.java:257)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processUpdates(DataTable.java:556)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:554)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:675)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:263)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: The stack trace contains always the answer. Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I added stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace tells that you need a (valid) `selection` attribute in `<p:dataTable>`.

Here's the relevant part:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:2458)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:2327)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.put(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:415)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.put(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:331)
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.setValue(MapELResolver.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:281)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:218)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:253)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.setValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:172)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processUpdates(DataTable.java:561)
```

Line 2458 of `UIComponentBase` class (the 1st line of shown trace) is:

```
if (value == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

Thus, `ValueExpression` value is `null`.

Line 561 of `DataTable` class (the last line of shown trace) is:

```
selectionVE.setValue(context.getELContext(), this.getLocalSelection());
```

Thus, `this.getLocalSelection()` returned `null`.

The `getLocalSelection()` method in turn looks like this:

```
public Object getLocalSelection() {
    return getStateHelper().get(PropertyKeys.selection);
}
```

Thus, `<p:dataTable selection>` attribute returned `null` (or is undefinied).

The solution should be straightforward: make sure it's not `null` (or is definied).

```
<p:dataTable ... selection="#{bean.selection}">
```